# C# how to give seperate forms unique IDs

Tags: c#, forms, instance

I need to give different instances of a form a unique ID number. for this project I can have upto 5 instances of the form open at once and the forms must be able to be closed and restarted to retain the unique number.

Any ideas?

Comment: what you want to do with retaining the unique numbers? you want to preserve data or structure of a given instance? do it through saving in the db/memory with a unique index, and fetch it back

Comment: I think he wants to have it so the form is almost a seperate program, so whenever it is closed and opened it retains this ID? can this be achieved in the app.config?

Answer (score 1):

Would sub classing it and having a property on it for the sequence work?  Something like

```
public class YourMainForm : Form
{
   protected int SomeUniqueID;
   ... rest of all code for the original class
}

public class FormInstance1 : YourMainForm
{
    public FormInstance1() : base()
    { SomeUniqueID = 1;}
}

public class FormInstance2 : YourMainForm
{
    public FormInstance1() : base()
    { SomeUniqueID = 2;}
}

public class FormInstance3 : YourMainForm
{
    public FormInstance1() : base()
    { SomeUniqueID = 3;}
}
```

Comment: Would this be retained though? I mean,  if you wanted 3 instances, they would only be assigned in order of the form running, rather than a constant ID for that program.

Comment: @RhysDrury, since it is a property of the base class, and each sub-classed instance (through its constructor) forces the value to 1, 2 and 3 respectively, when you create an instance of "FormInstance2", it will ALWAYS start with the "SomeUniqueID" value = 2... unless somewhere else in the class YOU decide to change it.